# How to print a string by printing letter by letter and in reverse in python

Tags: python, string, text, printing

I want to print a string in reverse and build it by printing letter by letter.

E.g - Word is: `string`

Ideal output is:

```
g
gn
gni
gnir
gnirt
gnirts
```

I want the user to be able to enter any word not just "String"

Code I have tried:

```
text = input('Enter a string: ')
reversed_text = ''
last_index = len(text) - 1
for i in range(last_index, -1, -5):
  for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):
    for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):

      reversed_text += text[i]
      print(reversed_text)
```

Comment: can you please share the code that you have tried

Comment: Shared it, but it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s=input("Word: ")
r=''
for char in reversed(s):
    r+=char
    print(r)

print ("Reversed word is %s " % (r))
```

This is the code I used, it works thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

```py
s='string'
r=''
for char in reversed(s):
    r+=char
    print(r)
```

This code does what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this with user input should be something on these lines:

```
newstring = "" 
enterString = (str(input("Enter a string to be reversed:")))
count = 0
for i in reversed(enterString): 
   newstring += i
   count += 1
   print ("Reversed string %s is this: %s" % (count, newstring))
```

Output with count of how many times till it gets the last character:

```
 Enter a string to be reversed:hello
 Reversed string 1 is this: o
 Reversed string 2 is this: ol
 Reversed string 3 is this: oll
 Reversed string 4 is this: olle
 Reversed string 5 is this: olleh
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses extended slice to reverse the word segments and separate each with a space. Other answers have separated the reversed word segments with a newline. Just replace `' '.join` with `'\n'.join` if you require this behavior.

```
word = 'string'
reversed = '\n'.join(word[-1:i:-1] for i in range(-2, -2 - len(word), -1))
print(reversed)
```

**edit**: Separated reversed word segments with newline to reflect updated question.